# Finding the height of a multiway (general tree) using OCaml

Tags: ocaml, utop, multiway-tree

As a newbie in functional programming (OCaml), I stuck with that problem.

I came up with a code shown below:

```
let rec height tr =
match tr with
  | Node(d,[]) -> 1 
  | Node(d,[t1]) -> 1 + height t1
  | Node(d,[t1;t2]) -> 1 + max (height t1) (height t2)
```

But the top-level (utop) for OCaml gives a warning:

```
Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a case that is not matched:
Node (_, _::_::_::_)
```

And when I run

```
let t : int gt =
Node('a',
     [Node('b',[]);
     Node('c',
      [Node('d',
        [Node('e',[])]);
      Node('f',[]);
      Node('g',[])])
     ]);;

height t;;
```

utop throws exception about match failure.

I also implemented this:

```
let rec height' tr =
match tr with
  | Node(d,[]) -> 1 
  | Node(d,_::xs) -> 1 + max (List.map height' xs)
```

and it returns with

```
Line31 |   | Node(d,_::xs) -> 1 + max (List.map height' xs) 
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type int list -> int list
       but an expression was expected of type int
```

In addition, I also tried another way:

```
let rec height tr =
match tr with
  | Node(d,[]) -> 1 
  | Node(d,[t1]) -> 1 + height t1
  | Node(d, t1::t2) -> 
  if t2=[]
  then 2
  else
  2 + height t2
```

then the error was:

```
Line26 |   2 + height t2 
                  ^^
Error: This expression has type 'a gt list
       but an expression was expected of type 'a gt
```

So, how can I overcome this problem?

Comment: The warning is pretty self-explanatory. What happens if you call `height (Node (1, [Node (2, []); Node (3, []); Node (4, [])]))`?

Comment: It returns with a match failure exception implying the last line in the code.

Comment: May we assume the definition of the `gt` type to be `type 'a gt = Node of 'a * 'a gt list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your problem**

Your `height` function expects a value of type `'a gt`. When you call `height t2`, `t2` is the tail of a list, which is a `a gt list`. If you pass this to `height` you get a type mismatch.

**How to approach this problem**

Given a tree definition:

```ml
type 'a gt = Node of 'a * 'a gt list
```

Writing a `height` function is straightforward, and I think you may be overthinking it given the number of cases in your pattern matching.

With any recursion the key is a base case. You have that:

```ml
let rec height tr =
  match
  | Node (_, []) -> 1
```

A node with an empty list has a height of 1. The actual data in the tree is unimportant, so we use `_` in the pattern match.

The only other possibility is that the list is *not* empty. So we can pattern match a non-empty list. Again, the first node doesn't matter.

```ml
let rec height tr =
  match
  | Node (_, []) -> 1
  | Node (_, _::xs) -> 2 + ...
```

Now we have to turn a `'a gt list` into an int. `height` will turn a `'a gt` value into an int for me. So why don't I just map `xs`?

```ml
let rec height tr =
  match
  | Node (_, []) -> 1
  | Node (_, _::xs) -> 2 + List.map height xs
```

Ah, but that turns `xs` into an `int list`, which we can't add to an `int`. We can sum that list using `fold_left`.

```ml
let rec height tr =
  match
  | Node (_, []) -> 1
  | Node (_, _::xs) -> 
    let sum = List.fold_left (+) 0 in
    2 + sum (List.map height xs)
```

**One more thing**

Using the `function` keyword, we can simplify this.

```ml
let rec height =
  function
  | Node (_, []) -> 1
  | Node (_, _::xs) -> 
    let sum = List.fold_left (+) 0 in
    2 + sum (List.map height xs)
```

Comment: your solution doesn't implement the height (it should be a max, and the constants are wrong).

Comment: @Drup in full fairness,  `2 + height ...`  was already present in the last code excerpt shown in the question itself (together with the fact that the last pattern is completely ignoring the first child of the current `Node`).